# C: scanf n lines of integers with for loop terminates after 1 scan

Tags: c, scanf

Function:

```
int scanEx(){
    int n=0; 
    n=scanf("%d");
    int arr[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("Enter a Number \n");
        scanf(" %d", &arr[i]);

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("%d", arr[i]);
    }
    
}
```

I am trying to read the amount of integers.
Then scanning until the amount is scanned.

But the scan ends after one input.

I have read about adding a whitespace before the scan value.
Did it.
But it still fails.

Probably due to '\n' ?

Could someone explain me how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Edit with hint of kaylum:

Function:

```
int scanEx(){
    int n=0; 
    scanf("%d, &n");
    int arr[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("Enter a Number \n");
        scanf(" %d", &arr[i]);

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("%d", arr[i]);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Compare this `n=scanf("%d");` with this `scanf(" %d", &arr[i])`. How is `scanf` used differently in those two instances (one is wrong and one is more correct)? Refer also to the [scanf manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) - to understand basic usage and return value meaning.

Comment: @RackCloud You got downvoted, I suspect, because some people here act as if there are two kinds of questions: questions you're allowed to ask, and questions that you should have been able to answer for yourself, and therefore shouldn't ask.  (Personally, I believe this thinking is fallacious, because given enough research, anyone can answer any question, so if that's the attitude, why have a Q&A site like this at all?)

Comment: Thanks! int scanf(const char *restrict format, ...); Thanks for the link. I would like to understand the manual in the future now. Tried to read it now. But the parameter definition is not clear for me.

Comment: You got downvoted, I suspect, because you did not show the output from your testing?

Answer (score 0):

Working function after the hint of kaylum:

```
int scanEx(){
    int n=0; 
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int arr[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("Enter a Number \n");
        scanf(" %d", &arr[i]);

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("%d", arr[i]);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Tip: Always check the return value of `scanf` before proceeding to use any of the resulting output variables. `scanf` can fail if the input is not valid for the format.

Comment: Tip 2: Use a good, modern compiler, and enable its warnings.  For your original code, mine printed `warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments`, which pinpoints the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I will research how to enable more warnings.

Comment: Also, as @kaylum said, read [man 3 scanf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) it will save you 100 hours of grief if you spend 1 hour now and be done with it. Doing so will show you why there is no difference between `" %d"` and `"%d"`, but the fact you have both speaks volumes about your understanding of `scanf()`. (hint: the only conversion specifiers that do NOT discard leading whitespace are `"%[...]"`, `"%c"` and `"%n"`. In those three cases including whtespace before the *conversion specifier* makes sense -- while `" %d"` doesn't ...)